# Upload of bmp file from IE results in corrupted image when saved in bd with paperclip_database

Tags: internet-explorer, paperclip, bmp

I'm working with [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), [paperclip_database](https://github.com/softace/paperclip_database) and mysql.

When I'm uploading a bmp file using chrome or firefox, the image is uploaded and saved into the database properly, but when I upload it from IE9 or IE10 the image gets corrupted in the database and I'm not able to get it back.

The only difference I noticed was the browser. I think it may be related to how each browser handles the file before uploading it, but until now I couldn't figure out what the difference is and what I can do to get it working.

Anyone having a similar issue?

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture the upload in both browsers, then compare what's different between them. Look in particular at any Content-Type headers on the request.

Comment: I was trying to get a cropped version of the image. I used { :thumb => "150x150#" } in my model. And when I check the original image it is ok, but when I check the cropped version it is corrupted. Now I think the problem is ralated with the bmp manipulation in the server side, I only don't know why it happens with IE. I'll try your suggestion.